# Can Spring MVC handle requests from HTML forms other than POST and GET?

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, http-method

Spring 3 MVC supports all 4 of RESTful methods: GET, POST, PUT and DELETE. But does its view technology support them on forms? If not, what is the real use of `method` attribute in `form:form` tag?

I tried to use PUT method on the form:

```
<form:form action="/myaction" method="PUT">
   ...
</form:form>
```

Generated HTML was:

```
<form id="command" action="/myaction" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
   ...
</form>
```

It is clear since [most browsers don't support other methods besides GET and POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856996/doing-a-http-put-from-a-browser). But Spring can handle it with additional `input` with name `_method` and value `METHOD_NAME`. Does it?

When I send specified form to a controller method annotated with

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT)
```

it claims, that request method *`POST`* is not supported. But why `POST` and not `PUT`? What actually happens under the hoods?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The use of the "hidden parameter" called `_method` is not specific to Spring MVC's tag library, but is also used by a few other client frameworks. Spring is just following the convention, such as it is.

In order to use this properly, you need to add a filter to your `web.xml`, (`HiddenHttpMethodFilter`, see [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html)), which turns the `_method` parameter into a "real" HTTP method representation in the `HttpServletRequest`. This is done as a filter to emphasise the fact the the lack of `PUT` and `DELETE` is a browser problem - the servlet API supports it just fine.

So if you want to use these methods in your form, you need to add that filter.

P.S. The reason you get the "POST not supported" message is that your form uses `POST`, and your handler is annotated with `PUT`, so it doesn't match. Because you don't have the filter defined, the `_method` parameter is ignored.