# Understanding How Spring MVC's @RequestMapping POST Works

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have a simple Controller that looks like this:-

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/groups")
public class GroupsController {
    // mapping #1
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String main(@ModelAttribute GroupForm groupForm, Model model) {
        ...
    }

    // mapping #2
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String changeGroup(@PathVariable Long id, @ModelAttribute GroupForm groupForm, Model model) {
        ...
    }

    // mapping #3
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute GroupForm groupForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Basically, this page has the following functionalities:-

- User visits main page (`/groups GET`).
- User creates a new group (`/groups POST`) or selects a specific group (`/groups/1 GET`).
- User edits an existing group (`/groups/1 POST`).

I understand how both GET request mappings work here. Mapping #2 is defined, otherwise (`/groups/1 GET`) will cause a "No mapping found" exception.

What I'm trying to understand here is why mapping #3 handles both (`/groups POST`) and (`/groups/1 POST`)? It makes sense that it should handle (`/groups POST`) here since the request mapping matches the URI. Why (`/groups/1 POST`) isn't causing a "No mapping found" exception being thrown here? In fact, it almost seems like any POST with URI beginning with /groups (ex: `/groups/bla/1 POST`) will also be handled by mapping #3.

Can someone provide a clear explanation of this to me? Thanks much.

**CLARIFICATION**

I understand the fact that I can use more appropriate methods (like GET, POST, PUT or DELETE)... or I can create yet another request mapping to handle `/groups/{id} POST`.

However, what I want to really know is...

.... **"Why does mapping #3 handle `/groups/1 POST` too?"**

The "closest match" reasoning don't seem to hold true because if I remove mapping #2, then I would think mapping #1 will handle `/groups/1 GET`, but it doesn't and it causes a "No mapping found" exception.

I'm just a little stumped here.

Comment: Why not use PUT for the update of a resource?  That would be the proper HTTP protocol.

Comment: The web form submission only supports GET and POST, and I'm not doing AJAX call here, thus I can't rely on PUT and DELETE at this point.

Comment: @limc, that is not really true, POSTs can be modified (on server side) to an other Request type with help of `org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter`

Comment: @Ralph, my bad... I was reading about that just now, and I realized that I can use the `_method` hack. I'm going through the spring source code right now, according to your post.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is complicated, I think it is better to read the code.

In Spring 3.0 The magic is done by method `public Method resolveHandlerMethod(HttpServletRequest request)` of the inner class `ServletHandlerMethodResolver` of `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`.

An instance of this class exists for every Request Controller Class, and has a field `handlerMethods` that contains a list of all the request methods.

But let me summarize how I understand it

- Spring first checks if at least one handler method matches (this can contain false negatives)
- Then it creates a map of all really matching handler methods
- Then it sorts the map by request path: `RequestSpecificMappingInfoComparator`
- and takes the first one

The sorting works this way: the `RequestSpecificMappingInfoComparator` first compares the path with the help of an `AntPathMatcher`, if two methods are equal according to this, then other metrics (like number of parameters, number of headers, etc.) are taken into account with respect to the request.

Comment: Wow... I look through `resolveHandlerMethod(...)`, talk about super high cyclomatic complexity code, I got lost after nth nested if-statements. I read the javadoc on `RequestSpecificMappingInfoComparator` that talks about the order list. I'm curious why they don't behave the same for GET and POST methods. In another word, if I remove mapping #2, why mapping #1 isn't handling `/groups/1 GET` but instead, Spring throws an exception...

Comment: @Ralph - nice explanation of the internals

Answer (score 2):

Spring tries to find the mapping which matches the closest. 
Hence, in your case of any POST request, the only map found for the request type is Mapping# 3. 
Neither of Mapping 1 or Mapping 2 matches your request type, and hence are ignored. 
May be you can try removing the Mapping #3, and see that Spring throws a runtime error since it does not find a match!

Comment: I initially thought the same too that Spring is finding the closest match. However, I realized it isn't totally true because if that is the case, I should be able to remove mapping #2, and `/groups/1 GET` should be handled by mapping #1 then since it is the closest match... but I'm getting a "No mapping found" exception here. I couldn't find any Spring documentation that explains more on this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a PUT mapping for /groups/{id}.  I guess POST would work too but not strictly correct from a HTTP perspective.

adding @RequestMapping("/{id}", POST) should cover it?

Comment: How do I submit the web form using PUT, without using AJAX calls? I'm still interested to know why Spring behaves this way with my current situation.

Comment: Maybe also check out how to mock a PUT with spring.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362791/can-spring-mvc-handle-requests-from-html-forms-other-then-post-and-get

Comment: You don't have a handler defined for the groups/{id} mapping.  I would also consider it a bug because I would be hard pressed to see the use case for the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score -3):

add @PathVariable to the Long id parameter in mapping #2