# Why first values in ArrayList always returns null in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, arraylist, thymeleaf

while i was coding on my little website-project for school, i ran into a mistake (probably by me) that is driving me crazy...

I got an ArrayList with objects (users) i created... currently 4:

```
public static ArrayList<Nutzer> users = new ArrayList<Nutzer>();
...
public static void init() {

        Nutzer testNutzer1 = new Nutzer("joey", "Gothra", "10", null);
        Nutzer testNutzer2 = new Nutzer("Badshah", "Gothra", "10", "Test");
        Nutzer testNutzer3 = new Nutzer("Ray", "Gothra", "10", "Baum");
        Nutzer testNutzer4 = new Nutzer("Sven", "Gothra", "10", "Niemand");

        users.add(testNutzer1);
        users.add(testNutzer2);
        users.add(testNutzer3);
        users.add(testNutzer4);
```

I then create an identical copy of that ArrayList within the Controller which then goes into my DTO as an attribute Value:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/edit" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showEditPage(Model model) {
        ArrayList<Nutzer> user = new ArrayList<>(users);
        model.addAttribute("formular", new NutzerErstellenDTO(user));
        return "Edit";
    }
...
DTO
...
public class NutzerErstellenDTO {                               //DATA TRANSFER OBJECT  
    @Autowired
    private ArrayList<Nutzer> besucher;
    public NutzerErstellenDTO(ArrayList<Nutzer> user) {         
        this.besucher = user;                               
    }
```

It then goes into the "Edit" template and is beeing processed: (sorry for long code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Edit</title>
</head>
<script th:inline="javascript">
function() sendDaten(){
/*<![CDATA[*/
var data = /*[[${formular.besucher}]]*/
/*]]>*/     
var url = "http://localhost:8080/edit";
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function () {
    var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
        console.table(users);
    } else {
        console.error(users);
    }
}
xhr.send(json);
}
</script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">                                                             <!-- AHA WTF -->
                <h1>Teilnehmer bearbeiten</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">                                                      
                <a class="btn btn-info" href="#" th:href="@{/Overview}"> Zurück zur Übersicht </a>
                <form action="#" class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/edit}"                                       
                    th:object="${formular.besucher}" method="post">                                             
                    <fieldset>
                        <span class="pull-right"> <input onclick="sendDaten()" type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-success" th:value="Speichern">
                            <input type="reset" id="resetButton" class="btn btn-danger" th:value="Zurücksetzen" />
                             <button onclick="sendDaten();">Click</button>
                        </span>
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Vorname</th>
                                    <th>Nachname</th>
                                    <th>Karten</th>
                                    <th>Wunschsitzpartner</th>              
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr th:each="u, itemStat : ${formular.besucher}">
                                    <td><input 
                                        th:placeholder="Vorname"
                                        th:name="|besucher[${itemStat.index}].vorname|"
                                        th:value="${u.getVorname()}" required /></td>
                                    <td><input
                                        th:placeholder="Nachname"
                                        th:name="|besucher[${itemStat.index}].nachname|"
                                        th:value="${u.getNachname()}" required /></td>
                                    <td><input
                                        th:placeholder="Karten"
                                        th:name="|besucher[${itemStat.index}].karten|"
                                        th:value="${u.getKarten()}" required /></td>
                                    <td><input
                                        th:placeholder="Wunschsitzpartner"
                                        th:name="|besucher[${itemStat.index}].sitzpartner|"
                                        th:value="${u.getSitzpartner()}"/></td>   
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it all just works out pretty fine when it gos back into the Controller with a post request
(Any tips on how i could turn it into a PUT request are much appreciated (points in the test xD))

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public String updateTest(NutzerErstellenDTO dto)
        List<Nutzer> test = dto.getBesucher();
        for (Nutzer nutzer : test) {
            System.out.println("test: " + nutzer.getVorname() + nutzer.getNachname() + nutzer.getKarten() + nutzer.getSitzpartner());
        }
```

At this point, its already lost as you can see here:

```
test: nullGothraTestEditWorksFine10*edited
```

The first Value is always "null" and i don't know why because everything else just works fine...

ANY tips or solutions to this? i already googled a ton and have found nothing.

**EDIT:**
This is my "Nutzer" class:

```
public class Nutzer {

    private String vorname;
    private String nachname;
    private String karten;
    private String sitzpartner;

    public Nutzer() {   
    }
    public Nutzer(String vorname, String nachname, String karten, String sitzpartner) {
        super();
        this.vorname = vorname;
        this.nachname = nachname;
        this.karten = karten;
        this.sitzpartner = sitzpartner;
    }
    public void display() {
        System.out.println(vorname + nachname + karten + sitzpartner);
    }
    public String getVorname() {
        return vorname;
    }
    public void setVorame(String vorname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }
    public String getNachname() {
        return nachname;
    }
    public void setNachname(String nachname) {
        this.nachname = nachname;
    }
    public String getKarten() {
        return karten;
    }
    public void setKarten(String karten) {
        this.karten = karten;
    }
    public String getSitzpartner() {
        return sitzpartner;
    }
    public void setSitzpartner(String sitzpartner) {
        this.sitzpartner = sitzpartner;
    }
```

Comment: For your small question, "How could I turn the post into a put?"  I believe that the answer is, you can't.  BUT, you can fake put and delete http methods in spring by using a hidden input field:  [Doing a HTTP PUT from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857064/42962)

Comment: ...i will look into that... thank you :)

Comment: There are a couple of things that don't totally look right in your code.  BUT, these are all guesses and things for you to try...  Change your DTO's constructor to just make the ArrayList the way you want it instead of injecting the ArrayList.  Then inject/autowire your DTO into your `@Controllers` instead of passing them in via the `@RequestMapping` methods.  I have a feeling that you have more than one ArrayList object.

Comment: Could you show your `Nutzer` class? Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: I edited the post with now including my ``Nutzer`` class

Comment: What exactly is calling the `init` method and where? Because a static initializer starts with `static {` not with `static void init() {` (sorry if this not of any use to you, it is the thing I noticed immediately). Beware that lists in class fields are not generally considered good design, especially if they contain data such as users.

Comment: yeah my ``init`` was basicaly just for adding a view users so i dont have to type as much by testing...

Comment: Does your problem still exist? Have you tried my answer?

Comment: sorry for not checking back... because not even my prof could tell me what my mistake was, i was building a whole new structure with ``@Repository``etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your real `Nutzer` class (and not some edited version that contains additional errors) then your problem is most probably the setter for the `vorname` field:

```
public String getVorname() {
    return vorname;
}
public void setVorame(String vorname) {
    this.vorname = vorname;
}
```

The setters name is misspelled: you named it **`setVorame()`** when it should be named **`setVorname()`**

Comment: Oh my goodness!!! Thank you so much Sir!!
I resolved it by building a completely new data-structure and thank god i think my code is now way better than it originaly was... I learned a lot with this project...
Thank you for your time and advice <3

Comment: EDIT: Actually it wasn't.... i recreated it with my old files and Spring would not even boot the project cause of an unknown "Setter"...