# How can i create a PUT method endpoint in Oracle REST Data Services using Oracle APEX?

Tags: rest, oracle-apex, put, endpoint, oracle-ords

I'm trying to create a RESTFUll API endpoint with ORACLE APEX using the PUT method (UPDATE) where i need to update the value of a column in a specific row, but when i try to test the method in POSTMAN it returns STATUS 555 USER DEFINED RESOURSE ERROR, and if i try to use the url directly into browser, it returns error 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED. I'm trying this way:

[image]

Does anyone know why it`s not working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tested that pl/sql block ? I see 2 errors. That could explain the 555 error

```
BEGIN
  update usu_int_foods
     set email = :email -- missing equal sign
   where cod_cracha = :id; -- missing semi colon
END;
```

In addition to that, what payload did you pass in POSTMAN ? Your code references a bind variable `:email` but you do not references that anywhere or mention how you pass that value in the call.

Also, accessing a PUT rest endpoint in a browser **will never work** (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856996/doing-a-http-put-from-a-browser))

Best place to start with restful webservices is read [Jeff Smith's](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/tag/ords/) very complete posts or [Tim Hall's](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-create-basic-rest-web-services-using-plsql#create-put-web-services)

Comment: This is 100% correct, nice answer Koen!